# Abstracting the Database client in the cake pattern

Tags: scala, initialization, polymorphism, client, cake-pattern

I am trying to create an abstraction for a SearchService using the Cake pattern. This is what I have currently:

```
trait SearchServiceComponent{
  val searchService:SearchService

  trait SearchService{
      def searchForSomething(..):List[String]
      def updateIndex(..):Boolean
  } 
}
```

Lets say I have a DbSearchServiceComponent and LuceneSearchServiceComponent as follows:

```
trait DbSearchServiceComponent extends SearchServiceComponent{
   class DbSearchService extends SearchService{
           //Initialize the db client
           //Implement all the trait methods
   }
}
```

Similarly...

```
trait LuceneSearchServiceComponent extends SearchServiceComponent{
  class LuceneSearchService extends SearchService{
     //Initialize the lucene client
     //Implement all the trait methods
  }
}
```

The issue I have with the above snippet is that

> I have initialized instances of lucene client and the db client in the Service implementations.

Ideally I would want to "mix-in" a "Client" base type that can be either a Db client or a Lucene client but I am pretty confused as to how to inject a polymorphic client type here.

Can somebody point out how I may be able to refactor the code so that I can inject different versions of the client to my implementations of the SearchService trait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I interpret your question correctly, but that's how you could use the cake pattern for this:

```
trait SearchServiceComponent {
  val searchService: SearchService

  trait SearchService {
    def searchForSomething(...): List[String]
    def updateIndex(...): Boolean
  } 
}

trait DbSearchServiceComponent extends SearchServiceComponent {
   override val searchService = new SearchService {
    // Initialize client, implement methods
   }
}

trait trait LuceneSearchServiceComponent extends SearchServiceComponent {
   override val searchService = new SearchService {
    // Initialize client, implement methods
   }
}
```

and upon instantiation:

```
val myLucenceApp = new Whatever with LuceneSearchServiceComponent
val myDbApp = new Whatever with DbSearchServiceComponent
```

where `Whatever` would typically be something along the lines of

```
class Whatever { this: SearchServiceComponent =>
   // ... use `searchService` and do lots of other things
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I guess was more along the lines of abstracting the client initializations for DB and Lucene. Since both DB and Lucene have different client implementations, I can't think of a way to have an abstract "client" that can be used for DB as well as Lucene. I have this hardwired dependency to these clients that I can't seem to get around.

Comment: [Daniel Spiewak](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLbdw06tKPQ) shows a nice way to use traits for initialization and shutdown in [this talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLbdw06tKPQ). As far as the abstraction of the clients is concerned, I suppose you are working with entities like users, services, etc.? These should be relatively easy to abstract over, independent of DB or Lucene. Could you provide an example? I'm afraid I still didn't get what you need exactly (no offense intended).